# How to redirect a named route with querystring in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, routes, query-string

I am new to Laravel framework. I am using 4.2 my question is i had a pagination    functionality 
    in a manageemployee page, I have created a route for manageemployee page.

```
Route::get('/usercp/manageemployee',array('uses' =>'ManageEmployeeController@getManageCompanyEmployee','as' =>'getManageCompanyEmployee'));
```

In this page i have pagination , if user was in third page, he want to delete one record.

now the page looks like **/usercp/manageemployee?page=3** After deleting a particular record in that page i need to redirect user to the same page.

**My Redirect code as follows**

```
return Redirect::route('getManageCompanyEmployee')->with('success','Record deleted successfully');
```

But with the above code user comes to the first page like /usercp/manageemployee. But after redirecting user needs to be in 3rd page /usercp/manageemployee?page=3.

How to acheive this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Everything you pass to your route that is not a route parameters, becomes a route query automatically:

```
return Redirect::route('getManageCompanyEmployee', ['page' => 3])
        ->with('success','Record deleted successfully');
```

But you could also do:

```
return Redirect::refresh()->with('success','Record deleted successfully');
```

Keeping the user in the very same page.

Or

```
return Redirect::back()->with('success','Record deleted successfully');
```

Depending on your use case.