# Laravel 5 Redirect::to with multiple parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to pass multiple parameters to a redirect in Laravel 5.  I tried the following but it gives me the error "The HTTP status code "1" is not valid."

```
return Redirect::to('availability', array('date' => urlencode(Session::get('bookingFormData.date')), 'expired' => 'true'));
```

My route is setup as follows:

```
Route::get('availability', 'BookingController@checkavailability');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The headers should be the third argument. The second is the HTTP status code. Hence, Laravel is complaining that the array you're passing isn't convertible into an HTTP status code.

Add a valid status code (e.g. 200 for "OK") as the second argument, and you should be fine. :)

Edit: On second thought, I don't think you're trying to send HTTP headers as the third argument either. You need to put those things in the session, e.g. something like this:

```
return redirect('availability')->with('yourParams', $yourArray);
```

Comment: So it's not possible for me to redirect to something like /availability?date=xyz&expired=true

Comment: Sure, you could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-str.php to append it, or have a look at Antonio's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765874/how-to-redirect-a-named-route-with-querystring-in-laravel-4-2

Comment: so i tried `return Redirect::route('availability', ['test' => 1]);` but still no luck.  Now it gives me `Route [availability] not defined.`

Comment: I managed to get it working using `return Redirect::route('availability', ['date' => 'test', 'expired' => 'true']);` - however, if I try to pass the date value as '05/09/2015' it doesn't send that value across.  I've tried urlencode() on that as well but still no luck...

Comment: @V4n1ll4 You can just send it as a unix timestamp `strtotime('05/09/2015')` and pass that across.