# Redirect a route with parameters in url to another route with these parameters (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a url and I want make a redirection and I want to keep the url parameters.
I'm using the **->with** method but it doesn't work.

Example:
http://mywebsite.local/product-name-random?select_article=710

I want redirect this url to:
http://mywebsite.local/father-category-of-this-product?select_article=710

I'm using this code but it doesn't work:

```
return redirect()->route('web.custom_url', $father_cathegory->seo->slug)->with('select_article', Input::get('select_article'));
```

->with() is not working. Nothing happens.

Im using Laravel 5.5.

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: Please check below link maybe help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765874/how-to-redirect-a-named-route-with-querystring-in-laravel-4-2

Comment: what does `$father_cathegory->seo->slug` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this way:

```
return Redirect::to('/admin/slider?rdStatus='. $rdStatus);
```

Comment: @Antonio Morales : Glad to help!!! and if my answer is work for you then please upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
redirect()->route('web.custom_url',[ $father_cathegory->seo->slug])->withInput();
```

it will redirect to route with input

Answer (score 0):

Using `->with()` you're flashing the session.
You could do something like this:

```
$to = route('web.custom_url', $father_cathegory->seo->slug) . 
    '?select_article=' . Input::get('select_article');
return redirect()->to($to);
```